# Is it possible to combine VPython and Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, joystick, vpython

I need to use a joystick for a vpython project, Is it possibe to combine pygame module and vpython to be able to use joystick functions of the pygame module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply making pygame joystick calls in your vpython event/animation loop? Drop something like this in there, see how it goes (after importing pygame and initing up joysticks).

from [pygame.joystick docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html)

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something        
    # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION JOYBALLMOTION JOYBUTTONDOWN JOYBUTTONUP JOYHATMOTION
    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
        print("Joystick button pressed.")
    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
        print("Joystick button released.")
```